# Rig has dissapeared and only shows as an orange dot at origin

Tags: rigging

just wondering if anyone knows whats going on with my rig. I previously worked on the pose and went to continue, but the rig isn't visible or selectable anymore. All that shows up is a dot at the origin. You can transform the bones still in the editor but not in the viewport. Is there anyway to get them to show again? If I append the rig to a file with another rig only the other rig is visible so it seems to be an issue specific to this rig. It's not a huge deal to start over but I don't want to run into the same issue again if it's something I can avoid.
Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file. thx.

Comment: Hello, Kevin, welcome to BSE. Without a share, I think any answer to this would have to be guesswork. Please use https://blend-exchange.com/. Without a share, this post is vulnerable to closure as 'unclear', until edited.

Comment: Sorry! added it now

Answer (score 4):

In the Outliner, select the rig, go to armature properties > Bone collections and turn on the visibility of the collection.

You can also switch the Viewport display option as Octahedral.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!